# How to temporarily disable keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: shortcut-keys

**KS == keyboard shortcut(s).**

I'm looking for a way to:

- turn off OS KS
- use the app that has KS that I like but that conflict somewhat with OS ones
- be back to using OS KS (turn them on again)

Preferably with KS. :-) So, I press my-KS and OS KS are off. I work with app, then press my-KS again and all OS KS are on again. Like <kbd>Insert</kbd> in `Vimperator`.

I can register my custom shortcut to disable KS, but:

- will it disable all but itself, so I can use it to "toggle" disabling?
- what command to use?

So, perhaps I'm looking for a script?